# Python - Generate random vertices around center (x, y) position

Tags: python, pygame

I haven't been able to find an article or an stackoverflow question around this subject as I need it.

I'm making  2D game and I want to generate a random shaped asteroid. Every asteroid has a center, a `X, Y` position, I want t generate let's say 8 vertices around it (the number of vertices is variable)

[image]

If I can achieve this shape now I want to add a random element, let's say a variable and random distance from the center to create a random rock shape.

[image]

I've researched some trigonometry concept called Polar to **Cartisian Coordinates** but haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to this goal. Although there's tutorials for it in Javascript, it uses libraries and functions that I would have to make in python from scratch.

**EDIT:** 
So your answer is focused on explaining the formula to get the vertices around the center, these are the things that I already know how to do,

1) Draw a polygon in the graphics library I'm using
2) Get random numbers

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: I tried to explain what I needed exactly, I even created graphics to help you understand. So tell me what part you didn't understand sir. Thanks

Comment: "I've researched some trigonometry concept called Polar to Cartisian Coordinates but haven't been able to figure out how to apply it to this goal" is the unclear part. I know what polar coordinates are, but I'm not sure what you want to do with them.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback sir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `random` library to randomly sample in polar coordinates. Sample an orientation, then sample a radial distance. In the following example I chose that the orientation would be uniformly distributed in `[0, 2*pi]` and the radius would be normally distributed with user input mean and standard deviation.

```
import random
import math

def generate_points(center_x, center_y, mean_radius, sigma_radius, num_points):
    points = []
    for i in range(num_points):
        theta = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
        radius = random.gauss(mean_radius, sigma_radius)
        x = center_x + radius * math.cos(theta)
        y = center_y + radius * math.sin(theta)
        points.append([x,y])
    return points
```

As an example of how to call it

```
>>> generate_points(5.0, 7.0, 1.0, 0.1, 8)
[[4.4478263120757875, 6.018608023032151],
 [4.407825651072504, 6.294849028359581],
 [5.0570272843718085, 6.17834681191539],
 [5.307793789416231, 6.156715230672773],
 [4.368508167422119, 7.712616387293795],
 [5.327972045495855, 5.917733119760926],
 [5.748935178651789, 6.437863588580371],
 [3.9312163910881033, 6.388093041756519]]
```

If you want the points to be wound in a particular order, then I would use something like `numpy.linspace` to walk either clockwise or counterclockwise to sample theta. For example

```
import random
import math
import numpy as np

def generate_points(center_x, center_y, mean_radius, sigma_radius, num_points):
    points = []
    for theta in np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi - (2*math.pi/num_points), num_points):
        radius = random.gauss(mean_radius, sigma_radius)
        x = center_x + radius * math.cos(theta)
        y = center_y + radius * math.sin(theta)
        points.append([x,y])
    return points
```

If you do not want to install `numpy` you can write your own similar version of `linspace`

```
def linspace(start, stop, num_steps):
    values = []
    delta = (stop - start) / num_steps
    for i in range(num_steps):
        values.append(start + i * delta)
    return values
```

Comment: Gonna try and let you know if we need to tweak it. Thank you sir for your answer

Comment: Ok, in this link you can see my code and the algoritm, I'm not getting the expected results, maybe I'm not putting the correct data somewhere. http://imgur.com/a/2aWl7

Comment: Thank you sir! any idea how can I generate them clockwise or counterclockwise since they are gonna be drawn in order? Maybe in this line: theta = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi) add some restriction based on the current index

Comment: you sure we need that library? I would love not to have to install it but if it's 100% necesary for this, I will

Comment: Just a perfect answer! Thank you so much! it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to choose at random one or two or three non-adjacent vertices, and simply move them a random amount which is not more than the distance to the nearest vertex.